# Help on determine a range of ID's

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

I would need some help to determine the range of specific id's, like in the picture below the output I would need is in column B, that ID is from A1 to A6. Anyone has any idea to determine this automatically in google sheets? [image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear why you would need to simply list ranges where a value appears. If you expect to use the ranges down the road in an `indirect()`, chances are that there are better ways to accomplish your end goal. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()` to get a mini report that lists the IDs together with the start and end row numbers, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { "ID", "row"; 
      A1:A, row(A1:A) 
    }, 
    "select Col1, min(Col2), max(Col2) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     order by min(Col2)", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid formulas that use the relative order of data rows to impart meaning to the data.

To return the addresses that contain the same strings I would use an approach that doesn't rely on the order of the data.

```
=LET(rng,A:A, unq,TOCOL(UNIQUE(rng),1),
   adr,ARRAYFORMULA(
     ADDRESS(ROW(rng)*(rng<>""),COLUMN(rng),4)),
   MAP(unq, LAMBDA(u,
     {u, TOROW(FILTER(adr, rng=u))})))
```

[image: example of formula with duplicate strings highlighted in the same color]

## Explantion

1. `rng` stores the range, Column A in this case.
2. `unq` stores the list of unique values from `rng`. TOCOL is included to remove the blank cell.
3. `adr` stores the cell address for each cell containing a value in `rng`
4. MAP passes each string from `unq` one-by-one into a LAMBDA function that stores the current string in `u`
5. The LAMBDA's formula filters `adr` where `rng=u` and returns a one-row array starting with `u` in the first column and the filtered addresses from `adr` in subsequent columns.

The LAMBDA's formula can be tweaked depending on your needs.

For example, to return all the addresses in a single cell:

```
=LET(rng,A:A, unq,TOCOL(UNIQUE(rng),1),
   adr,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(rng<>"",
     ADDRESS(ROW(rng), COLUMN(rng),4),)),
   MAP(unq, LAMBDA(u, 
     {u, JOIN(", ", TOROW(FILTER(adr, rng=u)))})))
```

[image: example of modified formula with duplicate strings highlighted in the same color]